# Spring 406 not acceptable request from ajax

Tags: spring, jquery, spring-mvc, jackson

i am getting 406 not acceptable and eating up all my time. I tried a lot, but it not getting solved please help me.

**ajax**

```
$('#cls').autocomplete({
               source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "classes.htm",
                    data: {},
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                        response(data.names)
                    }
                    ,
                    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(textStatus);
                    }
                })
                }
            });
```

**spring controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/classes.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=*/*")
    public @ResponseBody List<String> getClasses() {
        System.out.println("ajax");
        List<Classes> classes = homeService.getClasses();
        List<String> clsNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Classes cls: classes)
        {
            clsNames.add(cls.getName());
        }
        return clsNames;
    }
```

**config xml**

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd>
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.app.bluez." />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:resources/messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
            <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jndiName"/>
        </bean>


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:resources/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.app.bluez.domain" />
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />  
</beans>
```

Now i am getting this error on ajax request. I can see in XHR response like this.

> HTTP Status 406 -  The resource identified by this request is only
>   capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable
>   according to the request "accept" headers ().

**the headers**

```
**Response Headers**
Content-Length  1070
Content-Type    text/html;charset=utf-8
Date    Sat, 11 May 2013 21:59:55 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1

**Request Headers**
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Cookie  JSESSIONID=DDAC77BE351C26015C6494685E7AC225
DNT 1
Host    localhost:8084
Referer http://localhost:8084/Bluez/register.htm
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

jackson-mapper, jackson-core, jackson jaxrs are also added to project.
someone please help me out, i have seen similar question here in stackoverflow, the solution was downgrading to spring 3.1, is that true. I am using 3.2 right now..

Thanks and Regards

Comment: whith this same config, i downgraded to spring 3.1 and that works. Why not in 3.2??

Comment: have you tried to change version of jackson ?

Comment: ya downgraded to jackson 1.7 also

Comment: Did you try hitting the endpoint directly from a browser and not through PHP?  If so did you get the same error?  I just solved this problem myself with Spring 3.2 and it looks like you've done everything correctly.  The only difference is I'm using Jackson 2.x, not 1.x.

Comment: Take a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910031/jquery-autocomplete-throws-406-not-acceptable-error/27146752#27146752

Comment: I think this ques was too old