# Jquery AutoComplete Throws 406 Not Acceptable error

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I am trying to create an auto complete box in my spring mvc application by following this example
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-jquery-autocomplete-example/
Whenever I try to fetch the details it shows the following error in my browser
**NetworkError: 406 Not Acceptable** Here is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchTags.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    List<SolrResult> getTags(@RequestParam String tagName) throws Throwable {

        return fetchData(tagName);

    }
```

Here is my POJO class

```
public class SolrResult {
    private String id;
    private String label;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SolrResult [id=" + id + ", label=" + label + "]";
    }

}
```

This is my javascript

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#inputText').autocomplete({
            serviceUrl: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/searchTags.htm',
            paramName: "tagName",
            delimiter: ","
            transformResult: function(response) {
                return {
                    suggestions: $.map($.parseJSON(response), function(item) {
                        return { value: item.label, data: item.id };
                    }) 
                };  
            }  
        });


    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I fixed using Gson(), in this way:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getCustomer", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody String getCustomer(@RequestParam String query) {

    CustomerDao customerDao = (CustomerDao) ApplicationProperty.getApplicationContext().getBean("CustomerDao");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(customerDao.getCustomer(query, userProfile));

}
```